# Creating a colourmap plot in pyplot with random data and positions

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I want to plot a map (let's call it testmap) of shape (100,3) with a colourmap. Each row consists of the x-position, y-position and data, all randomly drawn.

```
map_pos_x = np.random.randint(100, size=100)
map_pos_y = np.random.randint(100, size=100)
map_pos = np.stack((map_pos_x, map_pos_y), axis=-1)
draw = np.random.random(100)
draw = np.reshape(draw, (100,1))
testmap = np.hstack((map_pos, draw))
```

I do not want to use a scatterplot, since the map positions are supposed to emulate pixels of a camera. If I try something like

```
plt.matshow(A=testmap)
```

I get a 100*2 map. However, I want a 100*100 map. Positions with no data can be black. How can I do this?

edit: I have now adopted the following:

```
grid = np.zeros((100, 100))
i=0

for pixel in map_pos:
    grid[pixel[0], pixel[1]] = draw[i]
    i=i+1
```

This produces what I want to have. The reason why I do not draw the random numbers in the loop itself, but iterate over the existing array "draw", is that the numbers that are being drawn are first being operated on, so I want to have the freedom to manipulate "draw" independently of the loop.
This code also produces double entries/non-unique pairs, which is fine by itself, but I would like to identify these double pairs and add up "draw" for these pairs. How can I do that?

Comment: you are plotting the axis combined with 100 random number.. Furthermore with this way of randint there is posibility to generate multiple same pairs [map_pos_x,map_pos_y] instead of 100. First you have to generate 100 unique pairs, then assign to them the values from  np.random.random and then create 100 arrays and stack them with np.stack

Comment: You have only 100 points, and you want to have 10000 pixels? That would be a very empty image. You need to clarify a lot what it is you really want.  For example [`tricontourf(map_pos_x, map_pos_y, draw)`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf.html) would show a color image created by data without the need to create a grid.

Comment: @AndreasFoteas the pairs actually do not need to be unique for my purposes.

Comment: @JohanC it's fine if the map is empty, even though here it's just exemplary; I might draw more data later on. I looked at the tricontour plot, but that is not what I am looking for. I do want the pixels.

Comment: So you could just make a scatter plot? `plt.scatter(map_pos_x, map_pos_y, draw)` ?

Comment: @DerAstrophysiker and if they are not unique which of all will be plotted?

Comment: @JohanC I mean, I could, but I want the look of a pixel map, so I would need to look into a lot of options of the scatterplot class to make it look like that, and I think it's easier to do it with the colourmap.

Comment: @AndreasFoteas In that case I would like to identify these pairs and add up "draw"; I updated the original post.

Comment: @DerAstrophysiker could post all the code.. it is not clear what is n_pixels_x,y

Comment: @AndreasFoteas Sorry, I forgot to change it back for this code sample! It's the number of pixels in x or y direction, so 100, in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create empty pixels, either with zeros (gets the "lowest" color) or NaNs (these pixels would be invisible). Then you can use numpy's smart indexing to fill in the values. For this to work, it is important that the `map_pos_x` and `map_pos_y` are integer coordinates in the correct range.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

map_pos_x = np.random.randint(100, size=100)
map_pos_y = np.random.randint(100, size=100)
draw = np.random.random(100)

# testmap = np.full((100,100), np.nan)
testmap = np.zeros((100,100))
testmap[map_pos_x, map_pos_y] = draw

plt.matshow(testmap)
plt.show()
```

[image: first plot]

PS: About your new question, to count how many xy positions coincide, [`np.histogram2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) could be used. The result can also be plotting via `matshow`. A benefit is that the xy values don't need to be integers: they will be summed depending on their rounded values.

If every xy position also has a value, such as the array `draw` in the question, it can be passed as `np.histogram2d(...., weights=draw)`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1234)

N = 100
map_pos_x = np.random.randint(N, size=10000)
map_pos_y = np.random.randint(N, size=len(map_pos_x))

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

testmap1, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(map_pos_x, map_pos_y, bins=N, range=[[0, N - 1], [0, N - 1]])

ax1.matshow(testmap1)

plt.show()
```

To show what happens, here is a test with `N=10` with the `matshow` at the left. At right there is a scatter plot with semitransparent dots, making them darker when there are more dots coinciding.

[image: second plot]

Comment: I see, I didn't know about the smart indexing, thanks! What about non-unique pairs, is there an easy way to identify them and just stack/add their data from "draw"?

Comment: Maybe sorting the pairs and then checking how many times the pairs appear in the sorted list? Or just going one -by-one as in @AndreasFoteas's answer. Also [`histogram2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) can be an option.

Comment: Yes, this is a very elegant solution, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

a solution is this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import itertools

#gets as input the size of the axis and the number of pairs  
def get_random_pairs(axis_range, count):
  numbers = [i for i in range(0,axis_range)]
  pairs = list(itertools.product(numbers,repeat=2))
  return random.choices(pairs, k=count)

object_positions = get_random_pairs(100,100) 

grid = np.zeros((100, 100))

for pixel in object_positions:
    grid[pixel[0],pixel[1]] = np.random.random()
    print(pixel)

plt.matshow(A=grid)
```

result:
[image]

edit:
since the grid is initialized to zero then just add the new value to the old one

```
n_pixels_x = 100
n_pixels_y = 100 
map_pos_x = np.random.randint(100, size=100)
map_pos_y = np.random.randint(100, size=100)
map_pos = np.stack((map_pos_x, map_pos_y), axis=-1)
draw = np.random.random(100)
draw = np.reshape(draw, (100,1))
testmap = np.hstack((map_pos, draw))
grid = np.zeros((n_pixels_x, n_pixels_y))


for pixel in map_pos:
    grid[pixel[0], pixel[1]] = grid[pixel[0], pixel[1]] + draw[i]


plt.matshow(A=grid)
```